# Twilio Video Android: RemoteDataTrack don't receive any event

Tags: twilio, twilio-video

I have a video chat with a text chat (like Google Meet) implemented on Web and it works pretty well, but now I'm trying to do the same implementation on a React Native mobile app, creating it in a native module using Twilio Video Android

The video is working as expected but the chat isn't, the problem is that I don't receive any event when a message is sent on the Web

I've put some logs and it seems that the listener for the RemoteDataTrack is being created but it don't receive events

All the code was created by reading the docs and looking at the example app provided by Twilio

My code:

```java
private final HandlerThread dataTrackMessageThread = new HandlerThread("DataTrackMessages");
private Handler dataTrackMessageHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // ...
  dataTrackMessageThread.start();
  dataTrackMessageHandler = new Handler(dataTrackMessageThread.getLooper());
}
```

```java
private Room.Listener roomListener() {
  return new Room.Listener() {
    // ...
    @Override
    public void onParticipantConnect(@NonNull Room room, @NonNull RemoteParticipant remoteParticipant) {
      remoteParticipant.setListener(remoteParticipantListener());
    }
  }
}
```

```java
private RemoteParticipant.Listener remoteParticipantListener() {
  return new RemoteParticipant.Listener() {
    // ...
    @Override
    public void onDataTrackSubscribed(@NonNull RemoteParticipant remoteParticipant, @NonNull RemoteDataTrackPublication remoteDataTrackPublication, @NonNull RemoteDataTrack remoteDataTrack) {
      dataTrackMessageHandler.post(() -> remoteDataTrack.setListener(remoteDataTrackListener());
    }
  }
}
```

```java
private RemoteDataTrack.Listener remoteDataTrackListener() {
  return new RemoteDataTrack.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onMessage(RemoteDataTrack remoteDataTrack, ByteBuffer messageBuffer) {
      System.out.println("Message recived 1");
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onMessage(RemoteDataTrack remoteDataTrack, String message) {
      System.out.println("Message recived 2");
    }
  }
}
```